# Analysis of an Equation Involving Square Roots and Real Parameters

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Consider the equation $$\sqrt{x^2-p}+2\sqrt{x^2-1}=x$$ For what values
> of the real parameter $p$ does the equation admit real roots?

I would like to know why I am wrong (or only partially correct):

$$(x^2 - p) + 4 \cdot (x^2 - 1) + 4 \cdot \sqrt{(x^2 - p) \cdot (x^2 - 1)} = x^2$$

$$4 \cdot x^2 - (p + 4) + 4 \cdot \sqrt{x^4 - (p + 1) \cdot x^2 + p} = 0$$

$$4 \cdot \sqrt{x^4 - (p + 1) \cdot x^2 + p} = (p + 4) - 4 \cdot x^2$$

Squaring, we have:

$$16 \cdot x^4 - 16 \cdot (p + 1) \cdot x^2 + 16 \cdot p = (p + 4)^2 - 8 \cdot (p + 4) \cdot x^2 + 16 \cdot x^4$$

Simplifying, we get:

$$-16 \cdot (p + 1) \cdot x^2 + 16 \cdot p = (p + 4)^2 - 8 \cdot (p + 4) \cdot x^2$$

Here, I know that I can isolate $x$ and start to find the values for $p$ from this, but I wanted another way, which would be analyzing $\Delta \geq 0$, once we want real values for $x$: $$x^2(-8p+16)+(-p^2+8p-16):$$
$$-4(-8p+16)(-p^2+8p-16)\geq0$$

$$p \in (-\infty, 2] \cup \{4\}$$.

I would also like to know if there is any approach using differential and integral calculus (derivatives)

Comment: Cursory study of [the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e8it5ycq32) shows that this equation has a unique positive solution in $[1,  1.16]$ (upper bound isn't tight) for $p \in [0, 1.35]$ (again, the upper bound is just a crude overestimate).

Comment: @SammyBlack Studying the graph is a good idea. What gives me pause is that this, mathematically, serves to give us insight, but I don’t know how this could provide us with a formal solution.

Comment: Hints: * there's an argument that shows directly that there is no solution when $p\le0$; * there's another argument that shows that there is no solution when $p\ge43$ (hint: how does the second square root compare with the right-hand side?)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $y(x) = 2\sqrt{x^2 - 1} + \sqrt{x^2 - p}$. The domain of this function can be defined as follows:

$$x \in \begin{cases} (-\infty, -\sqrt{p}] \cup [\sqrt{p}, \infty), \,\, p \ge 1
\\ (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty), \,\, p \le 1
\end{cases}$$

> $p \ge 1$

See that $\overbrace{\sqrt{x^2 - p}}^{\color\green+} + \overbrace{2\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}^{\color\green+}$ with $\min(y) = y(\sqrt{p}) = 2\sqrt{p - 1}$, which suggests solutions to $y = \sqrt{x^2 - 1} + \sqrt{x^2 - p} = x$ should exist for $+x$, specifically $x > 1$.

Consider the $2$ bounds

$$\sqrt{x^2 - 1} + \sqrt{x^2 - p} < \sqrt{x^2} + 2\sqrt{x^2} = 3x
\\\text{and}
\\ 3(x - \sqrt{p}) + 2\sqrt{p - 1} \le \sqrt{x^2 - 1} + \sqrt{x^2 - p} \,\,(\text{equality if } x = x_{min} = \sqrt{p})
\\\therefore 3x + 2\sqrt{p - 1} - 3\sqrt{p} \le \sqrt{x^2 - 1} + \sqrt{x^2 - p} < 3x$$

$3x = x$ has the solution $x = 0$, with $x < 3x, x > 0$

and $3x + 2\sqrt{p - 1} - 3\sqrt{p} = x$ has the solution $x = \dfrac{3}{2}\sqrt{p} - \sqrt{p - 1}$

Observe for solutions to exist,

$$
\min{(y)} \le \{x:\, x =  3x + 2\sqrt{p - 1} - 3\sqrt{p}\}
\\\implies 2\sqrt{p - 1} \le \dfrac{3}{2}\sqrt{p} - \sqrt{p - 1}
\\\iff 1 \le p \le \dfrac{4}{3}
$$

> $p \le 1$

$$\min{(y)} = y(1) = \sqrt{1 - p}
\\\implies (x, y = x) \text{ must atleast intersect through (1, 1)}
\\\therefore \sqrt{1 - p} \le 1
\\\iff 0 \le p \le 1$$

Hence, combining both arguments we see that

$$\bbox[5px, border: 2px solid black]{0 \le p \le \dfrac{4}{3}}$$

### Addendum

I do not see how calculus would be used in solving the entirety of the question. However, one can strengthen the above arguments by showing that $y(x)$ increases faster than $x$:

$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - p}} + \dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}} > 3 > 1 > \dfrac{dx}{dx}
$$ and hence for $0 \le p \le \dfrac{4}{3}$, where $\min(y) \le \{x:\, x =  3x + 2\sqrt{p - 1} - 3\sqrt{p}\},\,\, \exists x_i$ such that $2\sqrt{x_i^2 - 1} + \sqrt{x_i^2 - p} = x_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are fine. You only forgot that your equation makes sense only if $\color{red}{x^2\ge\max(1,p)},$ and to take care when squaring (twice): if $a\ge0,$ then $a=b$ is not equivalent to $a^2=b^2,$ but to: $a^2=b^2$ and $b\ge0.$

So, your first squaring gives
$$4 \cdot \sqrt{x^4 - (p + 1) \cdot x^2 + p} = (p + 4) - 4 \cdot x^2\quad\color{red}{\text{and}\quad x\ge0}$$
and the second one gives
$$x^2(-8p+16)=(p-4)^2\quad\color{red}{\text{and}\quad (p + 4) - 4 \cdot x^2\ge0}.$$

Putting the pieces together, your equation is equivalent to
$$x\ge0,\quad\max(1,p)\le x^2\le1+\frac p4,\quad\text{and}\quad x^2(-8p+16)=(p-4)^2.$$
Note that $\max(1,p)\ge1>0,$ and that $\max(1,p)\le 1+\frac p4\implies p<2\implies-8p+16>0.$

Therefore, there exists a (necessarily unique) solution $x$ iff
$$\max(1,p)\le 1+\frac p4,$$
i.e.
$$0\le p\le\frac43.$$
These calculation were so elementary that I don't believe in a better "approach using differential and integral calculus".

Comment: I asked about an approach using calculus because there are situations where elementary methods are much more laborious to find the values for a parameter.

Comment: If I take $\sqrt{x^2-p}=x-2\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and square both sides, we get -4x^2+4-p=-4x√(x^2-1)", the existence condition for the left side is different...

Comment: I don't see what you mean. The condition for the equation to make sense is the same ($x^2\ge\max(1,p)$), and the same techniques as in my answer lead (unsurprisingly) to the same conclusion.